# If I publish a lot, will I get a tenure-track job in math?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I want a tenure-track job in math. Is there anything else to know other than to publish a lot and have good teaching?

Comment: A lot of luck helps as well. The ratio of jobs to available candidates is not so wonderful.

Comment: Do you think there is a lot of randomness in hiring? One senior mathematician told me: "There was one candidate who was everything you could want in a colleague, but got nothing when he applied." Is that unusual?

Comment: My thesis adviser said something like this to me: "Did you trip and die on an escalator on your way here?" I said, "No." He said, "Well, you were lucky. That's the 'luck' you need."

Comment: @cgb5436 - sadly, that is not so unusual these days.  If you're not a Fields Medal candidate,  you're not guaranteed a job.

Comment: Do tenure-track jobs in Canada count, or is this another "implicitly USA-only" question?

Comment: Canada counts, too.

Comment: Ignore people's advice and get evidence from the CVs of people who have the type of job you want.

Comment: Of course the qualifications depend on the university.  If you do not get interviews at top universities, try less prestigious ones.  Many two-year non-research universities are now hiring only Ph.D.s

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: Except that the job market has gotten noticeably tighter.  I would not be hired today, so looking at my CV will give someone the wrong idea.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Right, look at CVs of recent hires and then extrapolate.

Answer (score 5):

Publishing quality papers and excellent teaching help, of course. Quantity isn't the same as quality, however, and your teaching needs to be attested to in some way, perhaps through letters of recommendation.

Nothing is guaranteed, however. There is a lot of competition. There is a personality aspect: how you come across in interviews. Lots of things.

Times are hard at the moment. I was once a good prospect for a solid position but the economy cut the prospects to zero and it took me quite a while (and a change of fields) to get a tenure track job.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you think there is a lot of randomness in hiring? One senior mathematician told me: "There was one candidate who was everything you could want in a colleague, but got nothing when he applied." Is that unusual?

Comment: @cgb5436 How can there *not* be some level of randomness when there are way more qualified people interested in positions than actual positions, and no objective measurement to rank candidates by?

Comment: There are intangibles, of course. That is probably a bigger factor than randomness per se.

Answer (score 2):

For tenure track positions with significant research responsibilities in pure mathematics in the US, evaluation is mostly by your best two or three papers, supported by a number of other papers.  Realistically, to even be considered these days, you need two or three papers that are in either a decent general journal (e.g. at least Israel Journal, but preferably at least Advances in Math) or a top subject-specific journal (e.g. Algebra and Number Theory).  Beyond that, you also need roughly a paper per year after your PhD.

Expect this to be a moving target as the supply of jobs continues to decrease.

Answer (score 1):

Academic job market is extremely competitive at the moment, and many tenure track jobs attract 100s applications per position, so the success rate is 1% or less. Hence,  knowing nothing about you personally,  I would say that, statistically speaking,  no, you won't get a job.

The rest depends on you. How much effort are you willing to put and how many sacrifices are you going to make.  How much debt are you willing to take on by doing degrees at  prestigious places and studying for your PhD? How much are you going to delay getting your first paycheck, settling down or starting a family? How many weekends and nights are you willing to spend writing papers and not having a proper rest or seeing your friends and family?

tl;dr: You can get a tenure-track job in maths by publishing a lot. However, this lot could be a lot bigger than you expect.

Comment: Actually, the last time I was on a search committee for a tenure-track job, the applicant with twice as many publications as any other applicant did not even get seriously considered.  It did not help that almost all his publications were in write-only journals, and the remaining few were in barely-ever-read journals.

Comment: That's also true. But one rarely starts by writing their first paper to Nature or Annals Maths.

Comment: My first paper (not counting the one I was part of as an undergrad) was in Advances in Math - that level of journal for a first paper is fairly common for people who end up in research positions, especially since a first paper is usually the result of work done while you still have frequent access to a PhD advisor.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I try to insert tacit caveats/disclaimers when reading your assessments of what is needed to get a job in maths, but I have noticed that you and I got our PhDs at similar times, and my observations while in the Canadian scene are that the bar was not set as high as you keep saying it is/was.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I am not denying that it is increasingly hard, and has been getting increasingly hard for a long time, to secure an open-ended job as a pure maths academic. I am just trying to say that there is a large amount of variability (and luck) regarding "what do I need to do to succeed".

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Advances in Maths is quite modest compared to Nature, Science or Annals Maths. Anyway, I agree that quality is also very important, but I believe my point stands as well -- quality improves with experience, which often comes with publishing more papers.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: There are certainly several people about whom I have the opinion that their reputations would improve if they produced fewer, more substantial papers rather than the mass of almost trivial papers they produce.  Also, certain areas are looked down upon because they have the reputation of generating large numbers of insubstantial papers.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Reputation is rather vague and hard to measure. Tenure/promotion criteria are much more specific and clearly affect one's academic career. And they are predominantly focused on quantity. Promotion/tenure panels often don't know how good each journal is, are too busy to get into such details, and simply count the titles. Until it changes, well, publishing more is a solid choice to promote one's career.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov: I get the feeling that the UK is much more bureaucratic than the US.  Here, we are still allowed to use our own collective judgement (including reading and interpreting what letters say) to decide on hiring, tenure, and promotion.